# Query cloud watch with boto3 for alb 500s

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to create a report of alb 500s and attempting to query cloud watch with the boto3 script below. When run, it returns a 200 but reports 0 albs, when I can see the albs in the GUI and grafana. I have triple-checked the metric name, namespace, and arns. I've also tried a call with Powershell and it returns 0 albs when i can see them in other places. I'm at a loss as to why it won't return the albs errors. It seems as if grafana is using some kind of metric data query and is able to pull them. Does anyone know what I am missing here? I've also tried get_metric_statistics to no avail.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='us-east-1')

response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/ApplicationELB',
    MetricName='HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'LoadBalancer',
            'Value': 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    ],
    StartTime=(datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=24)),
    EndTime=datetime.utcnow().replace(second=0, microsecond=0),
    Period=3600,
    Statistics=['Sum']
)

print(response)  # Print the entire response object

if response['Datapoints']:
    print(response['Datapoints'][0]['Sum'])
else:
    print("No datapoints found")
```